# Streaming audio from Watch to iPhone to use SFSpeechRecognizer

Tags: ios, swift, apple-watch, watchconnectivity, sfspeechrecognizer

I want to do speech recognition in my Watch app, displaying a live transcription. Since `SFSpeechRecognizer` isn't available on WatchOS, I set the app up to stream audio to the iOS companion, using `WatchConnectivity`. Before attempting this, I tried the same on iPhone, same code without involving the Watch - it works there.

**With my streaming attempt, the companion will receive audio chunks and not throw any errors, but it won't transcribe any text either.** I suspect I did something wrong, when converting from `AVAudioPCMBuffer` and back, but I can't quite put my finger on it, as I lack experience, working with raw data and pointers.

Now, the whole thing works as follows:

1. User presses button, triggering Watch to ask iPhone to set up a `recognitionTask`
2. iPhone sets up `recognitionTask` and answers with ok or some error:

```swift
guard let speechRecognizer = self.speechRecognizer else {
    WCManager.shared.sendWatchMessage(.speechRecognitionRequest(.error("no speech recognizer")))
    return
}
recognitionRequest = SFSpeechAudioBufferRecognitionRequest()
guard let recognitionRequest = recognitionRequest else {
    WCManager.shared.sendWatchMessage(.speechRecognitionRequest(.error("speech recognition request denied by ios")))
    return
}
recognitionRequest.shouldReportPartialResults = true
if #available(iOS 13, *) {
    recognitionRequest.requiresOnDeviceRecognition = true
}

recognitionTask = speechRecognizer.recognitionTask(with: recognitionRequest) { result, error in
    if let result = result {
        let t = result.bestTranscription.formattedString
        WCManager.shared.sendWatchMessage(.recognizedSpeech(t))
    }
    
    if error != nil {
        self.recognitionRequest = nil
        self.recognitionTask = nil
        WCManager.shared.sendWatchMessage(.speechRecognition(.error("?")))
    }
}
WCManager.shared.sendWatchMessage(.speechRecognitionRequest(.ok))
```

3. Watch sets up an audio session, installs a tap on the audio engine's input node and returns the audio format to iPhone:

```swift
do {
    try startAudioSession()
} catch {
    self.state = .error("couldn't start audio session")
    return
}

let inputNode = audioEngine.inputNode
let recordingFormat = inputNode.outputFormat(forBus: 0)
inputNode.installTap(onBus: 0, bufferSize: 1024, format: recordingFormat)
    { (buffer: AVAudioPCMBuffer, when: AVAudioTime) in
        let audioBuffer = buffer.audioBufferList.pointee.mBuffers
        let data = Data(bytes: audioBuffer.mData!, count: Int(audioBuffer.mDataByteSize))
        if self.state == .running {
            WCManager.shared.sendWatchMessage(.speechRecognition(.chunk(data, frameCount: Int(buffer.frameLength))))
        }
    }
audioEngine.prepare()

do {
    let data = try NSKeyedArchiver.archivedData(withRootObject: recordingFormat, requiringSecureCoding: true)
    WCManager.shared.sendWatchMessage(.speechRecognition(.audioFormat(data)),
        errorHandler: { _ in
            self.state = .error("iphone unavailable")
    })
    self.state = .sentAudioFormat
} catch {
    self.state = .error("could not convert audio format")
}
```

4. iPhone saves the audio format and returns `.ok` or `.error()`:

```swift
guard let format = try? NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchivedObject(ofClass: AVAudioFormat.self, from: data) else {
    // ...send back .error, destroy the recognitionTask
}
self.audioFormat = format
// ...send back .ok
```

5. Watch starts the audio engine

```swift
try audioEngine.start()
```

6. iPhone receives audio chunks and appends them to the `recognitionRequest`:

```swift
guard let pcm = AVAudioPCMBuffer(pcmFormat: audioFormat, frameCapacity: AVAudioFrameCount(frameCount)) else {
    // ...send back .error, destroy the recognitionTask
}

let channels = UnsafeBufferPointer(start: pcm.floatChannelData, count: Int(pcm.format.channelCount))
let data = chunk as NSData
data.getBytes(UnsafeMutableRawPointer(channels[0]), length: data.length)
recognitionRequest.append(pcm)
```

**Any ideas are highly appreciated. Thanks for taking the time!**

Comment: Great question and glad to see it working! Just one question - does the implementation you've wrote implies that the pair iPhone app need to be active or does it work without "waking up" iPhone?

Comment: @MaciejF Yes, iPhone will need to be active. You won't need to do anything to achieve this, though, since iOS wakes up every time it receives a WC message from Watch (doesn't work the other way around). Unrelated to that, should you attempt this, I recommend you downsample to 16 or 8kHz, so it'll also work on weaker connections (doesn't affect quality of speech recognition). I've been using this to do voice commands on Watch and it has worked like a charm so far!

Comment: Thanks for the replay! I had my attempt of doing this but speech recognition either doesn't work or work on just 2-3 words and then stops. Do you maybe have your working project on github?

Comment: @MaciejF Not sure how my employer would feel about that. I could have a look at yours, though. Did you downsample? If not, make sure iPhone and Watch are on the same WiFi.

Comment: Thanks actually after downsampling it started working fine! Now I'm just having a problem wen I test the app while my iPhone is locked. I'm getting "Domain=kAFAssistantErrorDomain Code=1700 "User denied access to speech recognition" - Have you encounter this?

Comment: @MaciejF I have to use the background audio "hack" to have the app do what it is supposed to. It doesn't really matter to us, since it won't have to be approved by Apple. So, I'm afraid I never encountered this scenario, my iOS part always runs in foreground. I hope you can find a fitting background mode or other workaround for yours! Just out of curiosity, though: when exactly does the error occur? Right after requesting SR? Maybe send some dummy messages to keep it in foreground during request, but that's just a guess.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I forgot to update the `AVAudioPCMBuffer.frameLength` after copying the memory. It works flawlessly now, without any noticable delay :)

```swift
// ...
data.getBytes(UnsafeMutableRawPointer(channels[0]), length: data.length)
pcm.frameLength = AVAudioFrameCount(frameCount)
// ...
```

Answer (score 1):

I would strongly suspect the problem is that you're not even close to keeping up with real-time because of how slow the link is. You're appending tiny (maybe as short as 20ms) samples of sound separated by long silences. That's not going to be recognizable, even to human ears.

I'd start by exploring CMSampleBuffers since you can set their timestamps. That will let the recognizer know when this buffer was recorded and remove the silence.

If that doesn't work, you'll need to do buffering to accumulate enough AVAudioPCMBuffers to perform the analysis on. That's going to be a lot more complicated, so hopeful CMSampleBuffers will work instead.

In either case you might also consider transferring the data in a compressed format. I'm not sure what formats watchOS supports, but you could dramatically reduce your bandwidth requirements between the watch and phone. Just be careful not to overwhelm the watch's CPU. You want easy-to-compute compression, not the tightest compression you can get.

Also, I don't see what sampling frequency you're configuring here. Make sure it's low. Probably 8kHz. There is absolutely no reason to record CD-quality sounds just to do speech transcription. It's actually worse because it includes so many frequencies that aren't in the human voice range.

Comment: I overlooked `SFSpeechRecognizer.appendAudioSampleBuffer(_:)`. I didn't think real time would make much of a difference, as the next chunk - whenever it is appended - would just be the next moment within the recording. I'll try using `CMSampleBuffer`, lowering the sample rate and maybe compressing the packages as well. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Turns out I just had to update the buffer's frame length after copying the bytes. No problems with bandwidth or anything. Text shows up on Watch w/o any noticable delay.

Comment: Wonderful! I've done this kind of thing over a custom channel from Bluetooth earbuds, but never from Watch. Very good to see it has the bandwidth.